# Как составить запрос?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Имеется 3 таблицы

```
recipe
+----------+---------+
| recipe_id|     name|
+----------+---------+
|         1|   name_1|
+----------+---------+
|         2|   name_2|
+----------+---------+

ingredient
+--------------+---------+
| ingredient_id|     name|
+--------------+---------+
|             7|   cheese|
+--------------+---------+
|            16|   tomato|
+--------------+---------+

recipe_ingredient
+----------+---------------+
| recipe_id|  ingredient_id|
+----------+---------------+
|         1|              7|
+----------+---------------+
|         1|             16|
+----------+---------------+
|         2|              7|
+----------+---------------+
```

Хочу осуществить поиск по ингредиентам, например пользователь выбрал 7,16 ингредиенты
, то я хочу получить такой результат.

```
+----------+---------------+
|      name|      recipe_id|
+----------+---------------+
|    name_1|              1|
+----------+---------------+
```

Мои варианты:

1)Выберет все рецепты где есть 7 или 16, но мне нужно строго что бы были 7 и 16

```
SELECT r.name, r.recipe_id
  FROM recipe AS r
    LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredient AS r_i ON r_i.ingredient_id = '7'
                 OR r_i.ingredient_id = '16'
WHERE r.recipe_id=r_i.recipe_id LIMIT 10
```

2)Проблема в том что не известно сколько всего ингредиентов в каждом рецепте, так что тоже не подходит...

```
SELECT r.name, r.recipe_id
FROM recipe AS r
JOIN (SELECT recipe_id,
             COUNT(*) c AS total_ingredients,
             SUM(ingredient_id IN (7, 16)) AS matching_ingredients
      FROM recipe_ingredient
      GROUP BY recipe_id
      HAVING total_ingredients = 2 AND matching_ingredients = 2) AS r_i
ON r.recipe_id = r_i.recipe_id LIMIT 10
```

помогите пожайлуста

Comment: @billy milligan, вы бы лучше сразу show create table показывали и делали sqlfiddle, вот за вас что-ли всё это делать щас ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока не предложили более умный вариант, [смотрите такой](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52ced/21/0), но рабочий:

```
SELECT * FROM `recipe` `t1`
  JOIN (
    SELECT `t2`.`recipe_id`
      FROM `recipe_ingredient` `t2`
    WHERE `t2`.`ingredient_id` 
      IN ( 7, 16 )
    GROUP BY `t2`.`recipe_id`
    HAVING COUNT(`recipe_id`) >= 2
  ) 
`t3` ON `t1`.`recipe_id` = `t3`.`recipe_id`
```

Подготавливая запрос, высчитываете количество "ингредиентов", по которым и будет происходить поиск. Например так:

```
$ingred_arr = array(7,16);
$count_ingred = count($ingred_arr);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `recipe` `t1`
  JOIN (
    SELECT `t2`.`recipe_id`
      FROM `recipe_ingredient` `t2`
    WHERE `t2`.`ingredient_id` 
      IN ( ".implode(',',$ingred_arr)." )
    GROUP BY `t2`.`recipe_id`
    HAVING COUNT(`recipe_id`) >= ".$count_ingred."
  ) 
`t3` ON `t1`.`recipe_id` = `t3`.`recipe_id`";
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы должно быть так:

```
SELECT r.recipe_id, r.name
FROM recipe AS r
JOIN (

SELECT r_i.recipe_id AS rec_id
FROM recipe_ingredient AS r_i
WHERE r_i.ingredient_id =  '7'
) AS r_i1 ON r_i1.rec_id = r.recipe_id
JOIN (

SELECT r_i.recipe_id AS rec_id
FROM recipe_ingredient AS r_i
WHERE r_i.ingredient_id =  '16'
) AS r_i2 ON r_i2.rec_id = r.recipe_id
```

Comment: на сколь положит сервер такой запрос если в таблице 25000 рецептов, 1500 ингредиентов и выбранных пользователем ингредиентов для поиска будет 10?

Comment: Попробуй протестить. Будет 10 вложенных запросов + 1 верхний.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.name, r.recipe_id
FROM recipe AS r

INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient AS r_i1
ON r_i1.ingredient_id = '7' and r. recipe_id=r_i1. recipe_id

INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient AS r_i2
ON r_i2.ingredient_id = '16' and r. recipe_id=r_i12. recipe_id
```

Возможно рабочий вариант, не проверял ... так на вскидку